BMX Logo and bike type please

Can anyone help with the identification of this logo and bike type please, any help would be great. I think it was bought from Alpine Bikes in Scotland probably Aberdeen and is about 15-20 years old.

Thank you very much all it's really helpful, it's my sons and wondering if we should sell it for him or hang on to it as it;s a cracking looking frame.

That is the logo for the Mirraco Bike Company

As for the bike - it appears to be a BMX.  We can see a crank with a pinch bolt arrangement, and a frame that has a "natural" metal finish with no paint and only a clear coat for protection.

Might be wrong but it looks like the 4130 designates a type of steel, so could it also be a steel frame bike?

@CaveJohnson true - 4130 is an alloy of steel, often called "chromoly"    I was commenting on the paint or lack thereof.

@CaveJohnson Very likely, as that seems to be the alloy used in a number of Mirraco frames.

@CaveJohnson that tidbit is worth an answer of its own.  Could you please post about the meaning of 4130 ?

The "4130" on the seat tube is a designation for a type of steel alloy. 4130 steel is commonly used for bicycle frames. Therefore your bike is a steel frame bike.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/41xx_steel
