Does anybody happen to know what brand this BMX bike is by that logo

It appears to be a maybe an m or a v possibly a W has a star. Its on my frame

Please add more photos of the bike on which you found this logo. And how old is this bike? Even a decade will help in searching.

Probable duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/95106/bmx-logo-and-bike-type-please

Mirraco as above

This question is similar to: BMX Logo and bike type please. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


This is a Mirraco logo
From bmxmuseum.com

R.I. P. Dave Mirra, Founded in 2006 by Dave Mirra and Jim Ford, Mirraco has since licensed it’s brand to Trek, Dynacraft, and now, Haro. Mirraco bikes are currently sold through online re- tailers in the US.
MirraCo began operations in February of 2006. It's a rider owned company. like many others that started because the founders loved the sport and wanted to do something on their own, rather than just riding for some big company. Unlike other rider owned companies, MirraCo was founded by the sportâ€™s most famous athlete, Dave Mirra. Having won more X-Games Gold medals than any other competitor, Dave has credentials that no other rider or bike company founder has ever combined in starting a company.
Dave is determined to be as successful in business as he is in riding by applying that same determination, work ethic, and passion to designing and marketing a line of products that bear his name. He knows the expectations of riders everywhere will be high and MirraCo plans to deliver products that exceed those expectations in performance, quality, and attention to detail.


This answer should be on the other question (Criggie) and this question closed.

@Noise The question was never marked duplicate - so I answered it.
